# what causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError to occur randomly?

Tags: java, ant, noclassdeffounderror

We've been getting NoClassDefFoundError in our server randomly. It Occasionally throws this error, and most of the time it runs without throwing any issue. What could be the reason for such weird behavior? Below is the exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.junrar.Archive
at org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.RarParser.parse(RarParser.java:75)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:527)
at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:602)
at com.xxx.attachment.AttachmentExtractionAPI.parse(AttachmentExtractionAPI.java:108)
```

`com.github.junrar.Archive` is present in the same jar which contains other tika dependencies.

I tried looking into the [source](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar/blob/master/unrar/src/main/java/com/github/junrar/Archive.java) of Archive.java. Looking for some possible runtime exception in static blocks. But it doesn't have a static block itself. What could have made this to throw exception **randomly** and run without any problem at times?

**EDIT:-**

We use ant for building. Below is the part of ant.properties that controls the dependencies of tika. Junrar is available as part of the tika.

```
tika_jar_file=${prod_home}/tikalib/tika-app-1.24.jar
tika_jar_srcdir=${tp_pkg}/tika
tika_jar_includes=**
tika_jar_excludes=org/apache/tika/parser/** org/apache/xerces/** org/apache/html/** org/apache/wml/** org/apache/xml/** org/xml/sax/** org/apache/xmlcommons/** javax/xml/** org/w3c/dom/**

tika_update_jar_file=${prod_home}/tikalib/tika-app-1.24.jar
tika_update_jar_srcdir=${tp_pkg}/tika
tika_update_jar_includes=org/apache/tika/parser/asm/** org/apache/tika/parser/chm/** org/apache/tika/parser/code/** org/apache/tika/parser/epub/** org/apache/tika/parser/html/** org/apache/tika/parser/iwork/** org/apache/tika/parser/mail/** org/apache/tika/parser/mbox/** org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/** org/apache/tika/parser/odf/** org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/** org/apache/tika/parser/pkg/** org/apache/tika/parser/rtf/** org/apache/tika/parser/strings/** org/apache/tika/parser/txt/** org/apache/tika/parser/utils/** org/apache/tika/parser/xml/** org/apache/tika/parser/*.* org/apache/tika/parser/image/** org/apache/tika/parser/ocr/** org/apache/tika/parser/csv/** javax/xml/bind/**
tika_update_jar_excludes=
tika_update_jar_update=true
```

Comment: I only see `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Archive.class.getName());` as code that runs in a static context. Could in theory throw a OOM.

Comment: OOM while getting a logger? Will check the possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

The key to this is understanding the error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
     com.github.junrar.Archive
```

Note that it says that it cannot **initialize** the class.  There are a few reasons why a class cannot be initialized.  These include:

- An unchecked exception was thrown (and not handled) during the initialization of this class.  If this has occurred, then there should be an earlier exception and stacktrace that tells you what exception was thrown and where.
- This class has static dependencies on another class that failed initialization.  There should be an earlier exception and stacktrace for *that* failure.
- Possibly there is a dependency issue, though I would have expected a *different* exception message in that case.

Comment: This is the complete stack trace. This class has no static block. The only static variable is java logger (the source link is available in question). And what's weird is that it doesn't always throw this exception. Randomly throws it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of NoClassDefFoundError is that  two different jar of your project depend on the same jar with different version.So you can use the  ide to  excludes the jar in your pom.

Comment: Here in my case, tika uses junrar dependency. I don't think we have bundled any other version of it.

Comment: could you post your pom.xml?Let me se your dependencies.

Comment: OK,I think the question is that tika depend on the com.github.junrar.Archive.And another jar in your project depend on  com.github.junrar.Archive too.Let us set the first version of the com.github.junrar.Archive to 1.0,and another 2.0.So the classloader will random load 1.0 or 2.0.The method to solve the problem is to exclude the 2.0 in another jar.

Comment: 1. junrar is only bundled in one place. (inside tika)
2. Only tika uses junrar. We have a separate adapter called tikalib to solve this kind of multi-version issue. So, only tika dependencies are available inside tikalib folder. Only tika will use that. `com.github.junrar.Archive` is available inside tikalib.